# How to watch Angular variables in a directive and Validate?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have written a simple directive in Angular through which whatever I type in a textbox i.e `ion-Md-input` should be validate in my directive for length 6. and I am trying to watch the variable like till it gets to size 6 and validate and based on it activate the submit button.

index.html

```
<div>          
<ion-md-input label="Enter the Device ID" hightlight-color="dark" type="text" ng-model="link" required ng-minlength=6></ion-md-input>               
</div>
```

Directive

```
vehicoApp.directive('ionMdInput', ['$http',function($http){
console.log('In ionMdInput');
  return {
    restrict : 'E',
    template : 
    '<input type="text" class="transition-input ng-model="link" required ng-minlength=6>'+
    '<span class="md-highlight"></span>'+
    '<span class="md-bar"></span>'+
    '<label>{{label}}</label>', 
    require : 'ngModel',
    scope : {
      'label' : '@',
      'ngModel' : '='
    },

link : function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel)
{
  if(!ngModel) return;

  scope.$watch(attrs.link, function(){ 
    validate();
  }, true);

  var validate = function() {
    var val1 = ngModel.$viewValue;
    console.log(val1);
  }
 }
}
}]);
```

Now even before I start typing the name in the text box. I get a undefined which remains like it. Now I want to see that value and validate it. How would I go about it ? 
I don't see any error after going through tons of SO posts.

Comment: Your directive doesn't look that simple at all. Can you describe what you want to achieve? The reference to the ngModel controller is a reference on the declaring element of your 'ionMdInput' directive - not on the ngModel declared in the template. - And where did you define an `attribute` called link? There is only a `link` value.

Comment: @Michael just updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you don't have `link` attribute. Then your scope config is not how you would set up in in your case. You can simply two-way bind `ngModel` attribute to inner scope model that will be used as ngModel for directive input.

After those changes you can set up watcher for this model:

```
scope.$watch('model', function() {
    validate();
}, true);
```

Entire directive will look like this:

```
.directive('ionMdInput', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: 
            '<input type="text" class="transition-input" ng-model="model" required ng-minlength=6>' +
            '<span class="md-highlight"></span>' +
            '<span class="md-bar"></span>' +
            '<label>{{label}}</label>',
        scope: {
            'label': '@',
            'model': '=ngModel'
        },

        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            if (!attrs.ngModel) return;

            scope.$watch('model', function() {
                validate();
            }, true);

            var validate = function() {
                console.log(scope.model);
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/wh8ylLbW4YpZcEKOryae?p=preview

Comment: Cool stuff.. but that `model` watcher will only get fired after `$modelValue` gets filled up when length reach to `6`

Comment: I wrote the same [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0S8tJoQjsr29VTzv4LCR?p=preview) as you.  So that I could understand the nitty gritty of it. But it's not working. Could you check?

Comment: Note that you have unclosed class attribute in directive template. So effectively you don't have ngModel.